# Tough question on Lebesgue measure and the distance function

Tags: integration, continuity

Here is a problem I cannot get my head around. Let $E⊆\mathbb{R}$ be Lebesgue measurable with $\lambda(E)>0$. Consider the distance function $d(x)=\inf\{|t-x|:t\in E\}$. Prove $\lim_{x\rightarrow y}\frac{d(x)}{|x-y|}=0,$ a.e. $y\in E$.

My thoughts... For $x\in E$ we have $d(x)=0$ so we get the limit to be zero. I can improve this for $x\in \bar{E}$, since then we can choose $(x_n)\subseteq E$ with $|x_n-x|\rightarrow 0$, and so  $d(x_n)\rightarrow d(x)$ and the limit is zero. But I cannot see what I can do with the general case... Any help?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I think Lebesgue's density theory is useful. It says at a.e. $x \in E$, $E$ basically contains an interval centered at $x$.